# jqgrid opening a link from cell value

Tags: jqgrid

[image]

How to make CopyRight column as Link ie when I click it, it should open in new tab

Comment: @Oleg, can you please help me.

Comment: Before to ask it is a good practice to read the documentation. The answer is very easy - just need to look at the docs.